# Sorting files to be used in for-loop in bash file

Tags: bash, files, filename, file-sorting

I try to remove duplicates from a directory with 20k files. I figured that duplicate files, although having different filenames, have the same filesize. So I want to sort them first on filesize and then feed them one-by-one to a for-to loop to compare the size of the current to the size of the previous file.

The problem is that filenames contain spaces, which makes the handling too difficult for me because I end up with the filenames getting split in separate arguments.

I tried the following two approaches:

1.

```
last=0
for filename in *
do
current=`du -b "${filename}" | cut -f1`
    if [ $current -eq $last ] 
    then
        rm "$filename"
    fi
last=$current
done
```

This works if the duplicates appear just after each other. And since the sorting order does not default on their size, a lot of duplicates remain.

2.

```
last=0
for filename in `ls -AS`
do
current=`du -b "${filename}" | cut -f1`
    if [ $current -eq $last ] 
    then
        rm "$filename"
    fi
last=$current
done
```

This does not work because the filenames are not passed to 'filename' correctly but cut in pieces since each space is considered as a separator.

How can I combine the two methods?

Comment: "I figured that duplicate files, although having different filenames, have the same filesize." Sure... but files with the same size so not have to be the same. Check out the command `md5`.  That one has a far better guarantee to match files.

Comment: and why reinvent the wheel? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/19552048/2920227

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that using utilities like `md5sum` and `shasum` are **far** more effective than file size at detecting duplicates (as mentioned in the comments already), the root of this question seems to be more about how to sort files when whitespace is included in the name.  I believe that you can use `ls -S1` to do what you're after as this will place the output from `ls` with one file name per logical line (sorted by size).  If you then change the IFS variable to break on newlines you should have what you're after.  Below is some example code illustrating:

```
ORIG_IFS="${IFS}"
IFS=$'\n'
for CURR_FILE in $(ls -S1)
do
    echo "Next file: ${CURR_FILE}"

done

IFS="${ORIG_IFS}"
```

Should you choose to go with `md5sum` or `shasum` instead you'll see that the command output prints the hash at the start of each output line followed by the file name.  You can then `sort` the output (which will put duplicate hash lines next to each other), use the cut command to peel the fixed length hash from the line start, and process in a way similar to what you're trying to do with file size.